# JMeter GET Request – How do you add query parameters from .csv file?

Tags: json, jmeter

I am having issues with successfully making a GET http request with query parameters reading from a .csv file. I am working with a JSON application. Thank you bunches in advance!

Path: /mortgagecalc/?amount=${amount}&years=${years}&maxInterest=${maxInterest}

[CSV Data Set Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIPOP.png)

[HTTP GET Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MiFh.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any "issues" with your configuration

Given you have `test.csv` file which looks like this:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

your setup should read the next line on next iteration and populate request details with the values from the CSV file:

[image]

If this is not the case for you:

1. Check the path to the CSV file, it must exist and be [readable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_attribute) otherwise your request won't be executed
2. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries
3. Check generated [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

Comment: You were right, my configs were setup correctly. I found the issue was the values being brought in from the .csv file had quotations which was preventing the request from going through properly. I opened the .csv file in TextEdit and was able to see the quotations there and removed them and now it works!